# Threadpool/Queue size limitation unsolved

Tags: elasticsearch, queue, threadpool

I am using ES to do some data indexing in Windows OS. However, I have come across with the following errors always. It seems that it would be a queue size or threadpool size problem. However, I could not find any document that reveal how can I change the Windows settings to solve it.

```
[2016-07-20 11:11:56,343][DEBUG][action.search            ] [Adaptoid] [cpu-2015.09.23][2], node[1Qp4zwR_Q5GLX-VChDOc2Q], [P], v[42], s[STARTED], a[id=KznRm9A5S0OhTMZMoED0qA]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@444b07] lastShard [true]
RemoteTransportException[[Adaptoid][172.16.1.238:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: EsRejectedExecutionException[rejected execution of org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4@cd47e on EsThreadPoolExecutor[search, queue capacity = 1000, org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@9c72f5[Running, pool size = 4, active threads = 4, queued tasks = 1000, completed tasks = 1226]]];
Caused by: EsRejectedExecutionException[rejected execution of org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4@cd47e on EsThreadPoolExecutor[search, queue capacity = 1000, org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@9c72f5[Running, pool size = 4, active threads = 4, queued tasks = 1000, completed tasks = 1226]]]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsAbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(EsAbortPolicy.java:50)
```

Is there anyone who have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with Elasticsearch, but with your indexing procedure. By throwing that exception ES is telling you that **you are sending too many search requests to ES** and is not able to keep up.

If, at the same time, you are doing indexing the pressure (memory, CPU, merging segments) from the indexing process could affect the other operations ES is performing. So, if you also indexing, do it at a lower pace as it's affecting the search operations.